# How do I write this Richpath code in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, svg

this code works for me in java but I don't know how I can write it in kotlin:

```
richPathView.setOnPathClickListener(new RichPath.OnPathClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(RichPath richPath) {
       if (richPath.getName().equals("path_name")) {
           //TODO do an action when a specific path is clicked.
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with the IntelliJ code translator in Android Studio

activity_mail.xml

```
<com.richpath.RichPathView
   android:id="@+id/idRichPathView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:vector="@drawable/ic_map" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
val richPathView = findViewById<RichPathView>(R.id.idRichPathView)

richPathView.setOnPathClickListener { richPath ->
   if (richPath.name == "path_name") {
      //TODO do an action when a specific path is clicked.
   }
}
```